# Insatlled TinyManaged NuGet but can't run due to missing libtidy.dll

Tags: c#, tidy

I installed the TidyManaged NuGet package and wrote some basic code to convert an HTML file to XHTML but when I run it I get the following error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.DllNotFoundException' occurred
>   in TidyManaged.dll
>
> Additional information: Unable to load DLL 'libtidy.dll': The
>   specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x8007007E)

I tried to add a reference to ibtidy.dll (both x64 and x86) that the GitHub page for TidyManaged link to but that gives the error

> libtidy.dll  could not be added. please make sure the file is accessible and that is a valid assembly or COM component.

Every other NuGet package I have ever used has always just worked, what do I have to do to get this NuGet package working so I can use TidyManaged?

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question but I have the exact same problem, however I found that the TidyHtml5Managed does't produce that error and its classes are interchangeable with TidyManaged (at least it didn't break my code).